# Draggable item added to a sortable list

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list and a draggable div:

```
<div id="draggable">Add Item</div>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

#sortable is already a .sortable().
I should be able to "drag" another item between any of the list items (first, middle, last).

How do I go about this?

Any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the option connectToSortable in the draggable options.

ie:

$('#draggable').draggable({ connectToSortable: 'ul#sortable' });

[See the docs for more info](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-connectToSortable)